# WhirlyGlobe Sample for android not working

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I have tried [whirlyglobe](https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe) sample code but it didn't work, can you check and make it working for android.
" MapGlobeTestFragment " this one "fragment class" is missing for android sample and its not present in library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you also created a github issue.  That's the right place to ask this.

Comment: thanks for updating but one more class connected with that one class "ConfigView". Please update ASAP. Thanks

Comment: I have one more question, is this code only working for android api level 18 or it run lower as well as higher version ?

Comment: It might run on a lower version.  18 was a client requirement.

Comment: thanks but got exception pls check, i have updated issue in github. its related to "mytester.so" file.